# Magento 2 Checkout Optimization

Tags: magento2, checkout

How to optimize both scripts on the checkout page.

```
static/version1629437274/_cache/merged/348790d02283d8460785fe15ee80b62b.min.css
    static/version1629807504/_cache/merged/a889b5206fb84f6264f7ad6049798085.js
```

Is anyone have any idea for the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Merged JS is no more recommended with HTTP2 so unmerge JS.

This will result in comparatively lower JS payload.

in case there are too many JS files then you can try advance JS bundling.

Use of CDN is recommended.
Check modules that are getting loaded but not needed on checkout.

Edit : If your JS size is more then 800 KB first step should be to remove module that are not in use or can be eliminated. Then do the above steps. A higher JS payload will never allow scores on mobile to be look really good. This is from our practical observations.

Answer (score 0):

I think, there is no way to optimize the merge file in Magento but you can use advanced bundling for this. With the use of bundling, the required data is rendered on a specific page. You can use the below modules for this:

**Github Module:**
https://github.com/magesuite/magepack

Or you can use Mirasvit Google PageSpeed Optimizer for Magento 2 Extension. This extension is also doing the same. But this is the paid extension. But the benefit of the use of this extension is that, no need to doing much on the server-side.

**Mirasvit Module:**
https://mirasvit.com/magento-2-google-page-speed-optimizer.html

Comment: Thanks, I will check and update you soon if it is useful for me.